# How to get data from <script> tag in web page source to .csv file?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Example webpage: https://subwaystats.com/status-1-train-on-2017-11-27.

In the page source there's a variable called "data," which has two lists of data (labels and data) that will become my "columns" in the .csv.

```
<script>
...
var data = {
labels: ['12am', '00:05', '00:10', '00:15', '00:20', '00:25', ...],
...,    
data: [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...],
....}
</script>
```

How can I get these two lists into a .csv? Any help is appreciated as I'm very new to web scraping.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: you will have to use standard string functions and/or regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reliable way to parse JavaScript is to use a real parser like [SlimIt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimit). With SlimIt, you can define a [Visitor](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor) to visit the JavaScript elements you're interested in. In your case, you want one that visits objects. Here is a visitor that finds all of the properties in an object whose name is `labels` or `data`, and whose value is an array, and prints the elements of the array:

```
from slimit.visitors.nodevisitor import ASTVisitor
from slimit.ast import Array

class MyVisitor(ASTVisitor):
    def visit_Object(self, node):
        """Visit object literal."""
        for prop in node:
            name = prop.left.value
            if name in ['labels', 'data'] and isinstance(prop.right, Array):
                elements = [child.value for child in prop.right.children()]
                print('{}: {}'.format(name, elements))
            else:
                self.visit(prop)
```

Notice how it recurses into the children of a node if it isn't one you're looking for - this allows it to find the properties you're looking for at any level (in your case, the `data` property is one level deeper than `labels`).

In order to use the visitor, you just need to download the page with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), and parse it with [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), and then apply the visitor to the script elements:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from slimit.parser import Parser

def main():
    url = 'https://subwaystats.com/status-1-train-on-2017-11-27'
    response = get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    scripts = soup.find_all('script')
    parser = Parser()
    visitor = MyVisitor()
    for script in scripts:
        tree = parser.parse(script.text)
        visitor.visit(tree)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Notice that I've set the `User-Agent` header value to the string from a common browser. This is because the website won't return a page if it detects that the user agent is a script.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. Looks like the website has multiple variables named "labels" and "data." Any idea on how to just get the ones I want?

Comment: You need to keep count of how many you've seen, or how deep you are (how many recursive calls).

Answer (score 0):

You can get `<script>` using `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` but later you have to use standard string functions and/or regex.

Simple example

```
data = '''<script>
...
var data = {
labels: ['12am', '00:05', '00:10', '00:15', '00:20', '00:25', ...],
...,    
data: [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...],
....}
</script>'''

rows = data.split('\n')

for r in rows:
    r = r.strip()

    if r.startswith('labels'):
        text = r[9:-2]
        print('text:', text)
        labels = [x[1:-1] for x in text.split(', ') if x != '...']
        print('labels:', labels)

    elif r.startswith('data'):
        text = r[7:-2]
        print('text:', text)
        data = [int(x) for x in text.split(',') if x != '...']
        print('data:', data)

pairs = list(zip(labels, data))
print(pairs)
```

after that you can use module `csv` to write in file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not uncomfortable with hardcoding stuffs, you can get the results with fewer lines of code. Give this a shot and see what it does:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://subwaystats.com/status-1-train-on-2017-11-27', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
items = soup.select('script')[10]
labels = items.text.split("labels: ")[1].split("datasets:")[0].split("[")[1].split("],")[0]
data = items.text.split("data: ")[1].split("spanGaps:")[0].split("[")[1].split("],")[0]
print(labels,data)
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked perfectly, thank you. However, after running it a few times it stopped working. Am I being blocked by the site as a bot? Is that going to kill my whole project?

Comment: When you find no results or any error upon executing the script then you can rest assure that you have got your ip address banned. Different sites have different policies so it depends when they are going to lift the ban. Meanwhile, you can use proxy to bypass that restriction. Thanks.